# How can BroadcastReceiver communicate with Service when ReceiverRestrictedContext cannot be cast to MyService?

Tags: android

I want notification manager to show a popup which has an 'X' button to close it.
When closed, I want the BroadcastReceiver to invoke a method on the Service which had registered the receiver and notification, and is the container.

```
RemoteViews remoteView =  createPopupView();
Intent intent = new Intent(myService, MyReceiver.class);
intent.setAction(CLOSE_BUTTON_ACTION);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(myService,
        MY_POPUP_ID, intent, 0);
remoteView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.img_close_selector, pendingIntent);
builder.setContent(remoteView);
```

I found that MyReceiver had to be statically defined in the manifest.
When I tried to dynamically register the receiver, it was not called at all when notification was fired.
But then I also found that my Receiver could not invoke any methods in myService because trying to cast context in onReceive(),

```
((MyService)context).foo();
```

or

```
((MyService) getApplicationContext()).foo()
```

causes...

```
    AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
Unable to start receiver com.myco.MyClass$MyReceiver: java.lang.ClassCastException: 
android.app.ReceiverRestrictedContext cannot be cast to com.myco.MyService
```

I suppose I could fire another intent from BroadcastReceiver, but it seems like another relay race - One BroadcastReceiver hooked to another BroadcastReceiver. Also I heard that broadcasts can be delayed.

So how does my BroadcastReceiver communicate with the Service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I tried to dynamically register the receiver, it was not called at all when notification was fired.

I am assuming that this `Notification` is for a foreground service. If so, a dynamically-registered receiver should work, if your `Intent` matches your `IntentFilter`, though you may need to call `setPackage()` on the `Intent` to get past the implicit broadcast ban on Android 8.0+.

> But then I also found that my Receiver could not invoke any methods in myService because trying to cast context in onReceive()

The `Context` passed to `onReceive()` will be unrelated to any other component of your app.

> So how does my BroadcastReceiver communicate with the Service?

If the `Notification` should only exist when the service is running, you should switch back to the dynamic registration approach. Or, use a `getService()` version of `PendingIntent` to talk directly to your `Service`. A `getService()` `PendingIntent` will trigger `onStartCommand()` on your `Service`, and you can put stuff in the `Intent` to tell you what to do, such as your `setAction(CLOSE_BUTTON_ACTION)` call. The `Intent` will need to identify your service instead of identifying a `BroadcastReceiver`, though.

If the `Notification` might exist when the service is not running, then either:

- Use the `getService()` `PendingIntent` that I mentioned above, or
- Use `startService()` from `onReceive()` of your `BroadcastReceiver` to start the service (if it is not already started) and trigger `onStartCommand()` (for you to do whatever it is that you are supposed to be doing)

Comment: thank you for your reply. my Service is started by the system at bootup time and so is available (almost) throughout. You said, `A getService() PendingIntent will trigger onStartCommand() on your Service`.  So will onStartCommand() be invoked two times? that would not be desirable.

Comment: my onStartCommand() currently returns `return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;` will there be any side effects?

Comment: @likejiujitsu: "So will onStartCommand() be invoked two times?" -- or more. Every `startService()` call triggers a corresponding `onStartCommand()` call. "that would not be desirable" -- then perhaps change your service implementation so that it is not a problem, such as by examining the `Intent` to see what triggered the `onStartCommand()` call. "will there be any side effects?" -- if you are not already calling `startService()` yourself repeatedly, `START_REDELIVER_INTENT` is pointless, as you do not have any meaningful `Intents`. Use `START_STICKY` or `START_NOT_STICKY`.

Comment: I will test it out next week. Mark Murphy, you are a 8th Dan sensei :)

Comment: Your suggestion... please confirm - I will no longer have a broadcast receiver? when I create the intent, I should now pass in MyService.class and I do not have to registerReceiver()?

Comment: @likejudo: If you use `PendingIntent.getService()` to create your `PendingIntent`, then you are correct. You will not need a `BroadcastReceiver` for this, and the `Intent` should have a reference to your service class.

Comment: ...and there will be no need for an intent filter, correct?

Comment: @likejudo: If you are using an explicit `Intent` -- one that has the actual component in it (e.g., `MyService.class`) -- you never need an `<intent-filter>`. An `<intent-filter>` should only ever be used if outside parties need to initiate communications with that component. So, for example, an `ACTION_SEND` `<activity>` needs an `<intent-filter>` to say "yo, I support `ACTION_SEND`".